# Screen connection with raspberry pi 3

Tags: pi-3, touchscreen

I am very new to raspberry pi 3. Sorry for silly question.

I have just buy raspberry pi 3 model B. I already have 7 inch touch screen which is belongs to my old tablet. I do not know if it is suitable for raspberry. Screen model is KR070PE2T rev:A. Screen has a flex cable 60 pins. How can i use it or can i use it?

Thanx.

Comment: Potentially, unless there is some technical documentation on it available to you. Or if someone has produced some kind of tutorial. Apart from that you are probably out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use your screen, if you can find an HDMI LVDS Converter Board [like this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-shipping-Raspberry-Pi-Simple-version-driver-board-hdmi-port-for-Raspberry-P-7-inch-LCD/32418252667.html?) for your panel, in order to connect your Pi via HDMI.

The Pi also comes with a DSI Connector, but you would need to get signals to your panel, use GPIO pins, a software driver, so not as simple as HDMI.